# Coloring PHP strings based on variable parsing in Emacs

Tags: php, emacs

In Emacs, is there some way to color double quoted strings based on their content? Ideally, any expression that gets evaluated within the string would be colored the same as if it were not enclosed within quotes. Currently, the entirety of strings are colored pink, which I believe is the default in Emacs for the PHP major mode.

Examples:

```
"a$b"
"{$a + 1}bc"
```

In the first example, `a` would still be colored pink but `$b` would be colored as if it were not enclosed in quotes. In the second, `$a + 1` should be colored as if it were not within quotes. Ideally, the brackets would also be their own color to de-limit expressions visually.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the expression by providing some examples?

Comment: Done. I refrained from doing so initially because I wasn't sure if I could explicitly color them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Emacs ships with a PHP mode, and it's unclear which one you are using. (It's probably [this one](https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode), but it could also be [`php+-mode`](https://github.com/echosa/phpplus-mode) or even something else).

[`web-mode`](http://web-mode.org/), which supports a number of HTML templating languages, does some highlighting along the lines of what you want:

[image]

The downside is that it's really designed around templating, not programming. It does pretty good syntax highlighting, but if you're looking for something with a bunch of `php-` functions, `web-mode` probably isn't a good fit.